# Row with closest column value

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  id serial
  timestamp bigint
  CONSTRAINT id_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
);
```

This table is used in an append-only fashion, so the `timestamp` values increase with the `id`. I need to find the row who's `timestamp` is closest to a specific `$value`.

Query 1: this requires two full table scans.

```
SELECT id FROM
  (
      (
          SELECT id, timestamp
          FROM records
          WHERE timestamp < $value
          ORDER BY timestamp DESC
          LIMIT 1
      )
      UNION ALL
      (
          SELECT id, timestamp
          FROM items
          WHERE timestamp >= $value
          ORDER BY timestamp ASC
          LIMIT 1
      )
) AS tmp
ORDER BY abs($value - timestamp)
LIMIT 1
```

Query 2: This one seems like it should be faster, but for some reason it's not

```
SELECT id
FROM items
WHERE scan.gpstimestamp >= $value
ORDER BY id ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

Query 3: I'm experimenting with a custom aggregate which requires a full table scan, but doesn't need to sort anything or load any indexes.

```
create function closest_id_sfunc(
  agg_state bigint[2],
  id bigint,
  timestamp bigint,
  target_timestamp bigint
)
returns bigint[2]
immutable
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
  difference bigint;
begin
  difference := abs(timestamp - target_timestamp);
  if agg_state is null or difference < agg_state[0] then
    agg_state[0] = difference;
    agg_state[1] = id;
  end if;
  return agg_state;
end;
$$;

create function closest_id_finalfunc(agg_state bigint[2])
returns bigint
immutable
strict
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
  return agg_state[1];
end;
$$;

create aggregate closest_id (bigint, bigint, bigint)
(
    stype     = bigint[2],
    sfunc     = closest_id_sfunc,
    finalfunc = closest_id_finalfunc
);


SELECT closest_id(id, timestamp, $value) as id FROM items
```

Why would query 2 be slower than query 1?

Comment: is timestamp user specified or does the db specify it? in other words, can we just get the row before and after the id instead and use those rather than having to use timestamp field? Additionally, is creating an index on timestamp field an option?

Comment: Slowness is due to full table scan as comparison is being done on a field that isn't indexed.

Comment: The timestamp is user specified, and no I can't put an index on it (don't ask :S ...)

Comment: The first query is better. And we have to ask. *Either* you have an index on the timestamp, *or* you won't get good performance. Tell that to the people who say you cannot have an index. There is a price they will have to pay (it might be a price worth paying).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe why is the first one better?

Comment: Ok, I take that back. Without the execution plans I cannot say anything. And Query 2, as it is written, contains a syntax error. Your custom aggregate solution might actually be the fastest.

Comment: Is there a way to correlate a group of ids by a timestamp range? This way to filter/prune down the set of possible ranges to actually search by timestamp? In other words, if timestamp X must be between id Y and Z, then you can include that id filtering criteria within the query which will get the index to be used and then scan the subsequent results using timestamp filtering for what's really desired...

Comment: Depending on how the id is generated, something more risky could be to include the timestamp within the primary key definition resulting in the optimizer likely using the index when just searching by timestamp -- the feasibility of this really depends on a lot of other factors though.

Comment: Your second query doesn't do a distance calculation at all, I don't know how to compare it to the first. With the first, your sub-queries can have `LIMIT 1` too (unless you want to do something different, and this question is just a simplified model). -- This might sound strange, but the with the [`cube` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/cube.html) (which supports one dimensional data too), you could directly use an index for `ORDER BY distance`.

Comment: @pozs the timestamps are ordered the same as the index (its append only). So it's looking for the "boundary" if that makes sense.

Comment: @IliaCholy if your data is really ordered that way, the second query is equivalent to `WHERE timestamp >= $value ORDER BY timestamp ASC` which is still most close value from the upper side only. On the lower side, there might be an even closer value.

Comment: @pozs accuracy is not very important in my use-case.

Comment: @IliaCholy that's not about just accuracy. There might not exist a row, which is greater than a supplied values, but a lesser row may exist in such a case. I'll look into it and post an answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second query won't work, because there might by a row before the provided timestamp, which is closer to the provided value. And accuracy is not the only concern here: there might not be a row, which is larger than the provided timestamp at all (and in the same time, a lower value exists).

Your first query looks efficient (when you use `limit 1` in the subqueries too). But yes, it requires two table scans, when you don't have an index, but that you cannot work around. You'll need indexes for huge performance gains. There is a few trick however, which can be used.

My initial idea was that, you can avoid cost of the outer query's sort, by using conditionals instead:

(Note: I'll use `ts` as column name, as `timestamp` is a keyword & shouldn't be used as a column name, unless it is escaped.)

```
with l as (
  select   id, ts
  from     items
  where    ts < $value
  order by ts desc
  limit    1
),
g as (
  select   id, ts
  from     items
  where    ts >= $value
  order by ts asc
  limit    1
)
select    case
            when abs($value - l.ts) < abs($value - g.ts)
            then l.id
            else coalesce(g.id, l.id)
          end id
from      l
full join g on true
```

However, this only caused a tiny performance gain in my tests (it seems PostgreSQL is pretty smart about sorting two rows only).

You can speed up your queries by using a direct "distance" calculation on some of PostgreSQL's geometric types. Note: these types usually use `double precision` for values and as such they can contain rounding errors. This will most likely not a problem, if your values are truly unix timestamps (in `bigint`).

Here is the query to use the always available `point` type's distance operator `<->` on `point(ts, 0)` (so the second coordinate will always be zero):

```
select   id
from     items
order by point(ts, 0) <-> point($value, 0)
limit    1
```

In my tests, this costs ~70% of your original query (or the CTE variant).

You can also use the [`cube` module's](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/cube.html) `cube` type & its (euclidean) distance operator `<->` (**9.6+** feature) on `cube(ts)` (so the cube will always be a one-dimensional point):

```
select   id
from     items
order by cube(ts) <-> cube($value)
limit    1
```

This is comparable to the `point` variant in speed. It will have some differences, when you use an index for it though.

(Note: you can initialize the module with `create extension cube;`.)

**Indexes**

So, the interesting part(s):

Your original query (or the CTE variant) can use the following (covering) index:

```
create index idx_items_ts_id on items (ts, id)
```

With this, your original query (and the CTE variant) uses index-only scans, which costs ~1.5% of the same query (without an index).

The `point` variant can use the following GiST index:

(Note: the `btree_gist` module is required for `id` to be part of the index. You can initialize the module with `create extension btree_gist;`.)

```
create index idx_items_point_gist on items using gist (point(ts, 0), id)
```

With this, the `point` variant costs ~1% of the original query (without an index).

The `cube` variant can use the following GiST index:

(Note: this also requires the `btree_gist` module.)

```
create index idx_items_cube_gist on items using gist (cube(ts), id)
```

Again, this is still comparable to the `point` variant.

**Conclusion (see edit later)**

You can achieve the best performance with using `point` or `cube` (latter requires 9.6+). Also, indexes can help you a lot.

Further notes:

- The `point` variant was actually faster sometimes (than the `cube` variant)
- PostgreSQL took a really long time to build the `cube` index & I don't exactly know why
- In theory, the `cube` index should be smaller, because it does not contain unnecessary zeros. But, because they are more general (N-dimensional), I might not be right about this. I suggest to try out both & measure (both index sizes & performance).

http://rextester.com/KNY52367 (the queries are here for `cube` too, but won't run, because rextester uses 9.5 right now).

Also, I tested a custom aggregate solution too (basically your version, but I used `language sql` functions to speed up a little bit, but still), it was ~10 times slower than your original query. IMHO, it is not worth at all. http://rextester.com/PLG94853

**Edit**: Just noticed, that the `btree_gist` module adds support for the distance operator `<->` for the basic types (such as `bigint`).

So this query will outperform even the `point` and the `cube` variant too (with a little):

```
select   id
from     items
order by ts <-> $value
limit    1
```

And this index will work best with the query above:

```
create index idx_items_ts_gist on items using gist (ts, id)
```

http://rextester.com/XUF56126